# Draw border around nontransparent part of image on canvas

Tags: javascript, image, canvas, html5-canvas, border

I'm drawing an image onto a canvas using `drawImage`. It's a PNG that is surrounded by transparent pixels, like this:

[image: isometric drawing of a patch of grass]

How can I add a solid-colored border to the visible part of that image on the canvas? To clarify: I don't want a rectangle that surrounds the image's bounding box. The border should go around the grass patch.

I did consider using shadows, but I don't really want a glowing border, I want a solid one.

Comment: AFAIK there is no out-of-the-box solution for this. You might have to resort to pixel-level manipulation with getImageData and putImageData.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

A bit late, but just draw the image *offset* which is much faster than analyzing the edges:

```js
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'),
    img = new Image;

img.onload = draw;
img.src = "https://i.stack.imgur.com/UFBxY.png";

function draw() {

  var dArr = [-1,-1, 0,-1, 1,-1, -1,0, 1,0, -1,1, 0,1, 1,1], // offset array
      s = 2,  // thickness scale
      i = 0,  // iterator
      x = 5,  // final position
      y = 5;
  
  // draw images at offsets from the array scaled by s
  for(; i < dArr.length; i += 2)
    ctx.drawImage(img, x + dArr[i]*s, y + dArr[i+1]*s);
  
  // fill with color
  ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-in";
  ctx.fillStyle = "red";
  ctx.fillRect(0,0,canvas.width, canvas.height);
  
  // draw original image in normal mode
  ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";
  ctx.drawImage(img, x, y);
}
```

```html
<canvas id=canvas width=500 height=500></canvas>
```

Comment: Hi Ken and welcome back! Upvote for an efficient answer.

Comment: @epistemex: I love the succinctness of your code compared to the other answer, but I'm having a bit of trouble getting it to work perfectly and don't understand why. Could you please explain exactly how it works a bit more? Especially why the `dArr` variable has 8 coordinate pairs? Exactly how do they relate to the canvas? I'm using this to border some very irregular paths that are already being scaled, transformed and otherwise manipulated all over the place before finally drawing the border around them, so sometimes the border is partially cut off. Any ideas how I could fix this? Thanks!

Comment: @Kenny83 sure. The dArr is, as stated, just an offset arr. for convenience. It isn't related to the canvas per-se. Each pair is a (x,y) offset *relative* to where we want to draw. So instead of using 8 drawImage calls and manually add the offsets (f.ex. x+1, y- etc) we just iterate the array & apply the pairs from there. Why? thicker borders drawing in only 4 directions will start to create "gaps" at the corners so you want to draw more instances to make the border smoother. An array like here can help with that but isn't the only way.

Comment: @Kenny83 Not sure how to fix the problem you describe without seeing the code. I'd suggest opening a question for it. That way we can have a closer look at it.

Comment: what about the images that are transparent ? How do i solve that problem ?

Comment: Should be the accepted answer

Comment: This only works if this is the *only* thing on the canvas, since it's painting the entire canvas red, not just what was just drawn.  I guess that's OK if you have a separate canvas for every sprite, but most of the time you don't.

Comment: This works only if the image doesn't have parts that are relatively small compared to the border thickness, otherwise you'll end up with something really weird (for example, change the thickness to 10 in your example and see), unless you keep increasing the number of offset copies.

Comment: For future reference, the `dArr` didn't really work for me as I had quite a lot of small images to work with but after changing it to `[-.5,-.5, 0,-1, .5,-.5, -1,0, 1,0, -.5,.5, 0,1, .5,.5]` it started to work pretty well

Answer (score 24):

[image] ==> [image] ==> [image]

*First, attributions:*

As @Philipp says, you'll need to analyze pixel data to get your outline border.

You can use the "Marching Squares" algorithm to determine which transparent pixels border the non-transparent grass pixels. You can read more about the Marching Squares algorithm here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marching_squares

Michael Bostock has a very nice plugin version of Marching Squares in his **d3** data visualization application (IMHO, d3 is the best open-source data visualization program available). Here's a link to the plugin: https://github.com/d3/d3-plugins/tree/master/geom/contour

**You can outline the border of your grass image like this:**

- Draw your image on the canvas
- Grab the image's pixel data using `.getImageData`
- Configure the plug-in to look for transparent pixels bordering opaque pixels

  ```
  // This is used by the marching ants algorithm
  // to determine the outline of the non-transparent
  // pixels on the image using pixel data
  var defineNonTransparent=function(x,y){
      var a=data[(y*cw+x)*4+3];
      return(a>20);
  }
  ```
- Call the plugin which returns a set of points which outline the border of your image.

  ```
  // call the marching ants algorithm
  // to get the outline path of the image
  // (outline=outside path of transparent pixels
  points=geom.contour(defineNonTransparent);
  ```
- Use the set of points to draw a path around your image.

**Here's annotated code and a Demo:**

```js
// Marching Squares Edge Detection
// this is a "marching ants" algorithm used to calc the outline path
(function() {
  // d3-plugin for calculating outline paths
  // License: https://github.com/d3/d3-plugins/blob/master/LICENSE
  //
  // Copyright (c) 2012-2014, Michael Bostock
  // All rights reserved.
  //
  //  Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without
  //  modification, are permitted provided that the following conditions are met:
  //* Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright notice, this
  //  list of conditions and the following disclaimer.
  //* Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above copyright notice,
  //  this list of conditions and the following disclaimer in the documentation
  //  and/or other materials provided with the distribution.
  //* The name Michael Bostock may not be used to endorse or promote products
  //  derived from this software without specific prior written permission.
  // THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY THE COPYRIGHT HOLDERS AND CONTRIBUTORS "AS IS" AND ANY EXPRESS OR IMPLIED WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, THE IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE ARE DISCLAIMED. IN NO EVENT SHALL MICHAEL BOSTOCK BE LIABLE FOR ANY DIRECT, INDIRECT, INCIDENTAL, SPECIAL, EXEMPLARY, OR CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES (INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, PROCUREMENT OF SUBSTITUTE GOODS OR SERVICES; LOSS OF USE, DATA, OR PROFITS; OR BUSINESS INTERRUPTION) HOWEVER CAUSED AND ON ANY THEORY OF LIABILITY, WHETHER IN CONTRACT, STRICT LIABILITY, OR TORT (INCLUDING NEGLIGENCE OR OTHERWISE) ARISING IN ANY WAY OUT OF THE USE OF THIS SOFTWARE, EVEN IF ADVISED OF THE POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE. 
  geom = {}; 
  geom.contour = function(grid, start) { 
    var s = start || d3_geom_contourStart(grid), // starting point 
        c = [],    // contour polygon 
        x = s[0],  // current x position 
        y = s[1],  // current y position 
        dx = 0,    // next x direction 
        dy = 0,    // next y direction 
        pdx = NaN, // previous x direction 
        pdy = NaN, // previous y direction 
        i = 0; 

    do { 
      // determine marching squares index 
      i = 0; 
      if (grid(x-1, y-1)) i += 1; 
      if (grid(x,   y-1)) i += 2; 
      if (grid(x-1, y  )) i += 4; 
      if (grid(x,   y  )) i += 8; 

      // determine next direction 
      if (i === 6) { 
        dx = pdy === -1 ? -1 : 1; 
        dy = 0; 
      } else if (i === 9) { 
        dx = 0; 
        dy = pdx === 1 ? -1 : 1; 
      } else { 
        dx = d3_geom_contourDx[i]; 
        dy = d3_geom_contourDy[i]; 
      } 

      // update contour polygon 
      if (dx != pdx && dy != pdy) { 
        c.push([x, y]); 
        pdx = dx; 
        pdy = dy; 
      } 

      x += dx; 
      y += dy; 
    } while (s[0] != x || s[1] != y); 

    return c; 
  }; 

  // lookup tables for marching directions 
  var d3_geom_contourDx = [1, 0, 1, 1,-1, 0,-1, 1,0, 0,0,0,-1, 0,-1,NaN], 
      d3_geom_contourDy = [0,-1, 0, 0, 0,-1, 0, 0,1,-1,1,1, 0,-1, 0,NaN]; 

  function d3_geom_contourStart(grid) { 
    var x = 0, 
        y = 0; 

    // search for a starting point; begin at origin 
    // and proceed along outward-expanding diagonals 
    while (true) { 
      if (grid(x,y)) { 
        return [x,y]; 
      } 
      if (x === 0) { 
        x = y + 1; 
        y = 0; 
      } else { 
        x = x - 1; 
        y = y + 1; 
      } 
    } 
  } 

})();


//////////////////////////////////////////

// canvas related variables
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
var cw=canvas.width;
var ch=canvas.height;

// checkbox to show/hide the original image
var $showImage=$("#showImage");
$showImage.prop('checked', true);

// checkbox to show/hide the path outline
var $showOutline=$("#showOutline");
$showOutline.prop('checked', true);

// an array of points that defines the outline path
var points;

// pixel data of this image for the defineNonTransparent 
// function to use
var imgData,data;

// This is used by the marching ants algorithm
// to determine the outline of the non-transparent
// pixels on the image
var defineNonTransparent=function(x,y){
  var a=data[(y*cw+x)*4+3];
  return(a>20);
}

// load the image
var img=new Image();
img.crossOrigin="anonymous";
img.onload=function(){

  // draw the image
  // (this time to grab the image's pixel data
  ctx.drawImage(img,canvas.width/2-img.width/2,canvas.height/2-img.height/2);

  // grab the image's pixel data
  imgData=ctx.getImageData(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
  data=imgData.data;

  // call the marching ants algorithm
  // to get the outline path of the image
  // (outline=outside path of transparent pixels
  points=geom.contour(defineNonTransparent);

  ctx.strokeStyle="red";
  ctx.lineWidth=2;

  $showImage.change(function(){ redraw(); });

  $showOutline.change(function(){ redraw(); });

  redraw();

}
img.src="http://i.imgur.com/QcxIJxa.png";

// redraw the canvas
// user determines if original-image or outline path or both are visible
function redraw(){

  // clear the canvas
  ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);

  // draw the image
  if($showImage.is(':checked')){
    ctx.drawImage(img,canvas.width/2-img.width/2,canvas.height/2-img.height/2);
  }

  // draw the path (consisting of connected points)
  if($showOutline.is(':checked')){
    // draw outline path
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(points[0][0],points[0][4]);
    for(var i=1;i<points.length;i++){
      var point=points[i];
      ctx.lineTo(point[0],point[1]);
    }
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.stroke();
  }

}
```

```css
body{ background-color: ivory; }
canvas{border:1px solid red;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="showImage" />Show Image<br>
<input type="checkbox" id="showOutline" />Show Outline Path<br>
<canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=450></canvas>
```

Comment: Amazing answer! Works perfectly.

Comment: While *K3N's* answer is more adecuate to this question, I'd like to thank you for providing a way to get the path's points, which can get you more than just an outline :)

Comment: Works great. Can it be used for image with two separate shape like for example - http://www.sportsauthority.com/graphics/product_images/pTSA-19707622p275w.jpg

Comment: The snippet is broken because the example image is returning a 404.

Comment: Note, this method will only outline *one* shape per image (to answer @susrut316 's question).

Answer (score 3):

I was looking for a way to do this and it seems there are only laborious solutions.

I came up with a little workaround using shadows and a loop to display them all around the image:

```
// Shadow color and blur
// To get a blurry effect use rgba() with a low opacity as it will be overlaid
context.shadowColor = "red";
context.shadowBlur = 0;

// X offset loop
for(var x = -2; x <= 2; x++){
    // Y offset loop
    for(var y = -2; y <= 2; y++){
        // Set shadow offset
        context.shadowOffsetX = x;
        context.shadowOffsetY = y;

        // Draw image with shadow
        context.drawImage(img, left, top, width, height);
    }
}
```