# Javascript draw border around shape on Image canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas

I am searching for a solution to draw a border around all shapes on an Image. I have already tried this solution [Draw border around nontransparent part of image on canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28207232/draw-border-around-nontransparent-part-of-image-on-canvas) but this doesnt work for me.

Imagine this png
[image]

the solution I am looking for should look like this
[image]

is there any libary/solution?

Thank you

Comment: How exactly the question you posted doesn't work? Does it draw? Does it skip some  objects?

Comment: The solution I mentioned does only work for small images (300x300). If I load Images with higher resolution the app will freeze. If I load the first Image in the example with a small resolution the app will only draw a border around the image itself not around the obstacles.

Answer (score 2):

If you're drawing the all the shapes using `ctx.fill()`, you can just call `ctx.stroke()` before each call to `ctx.fill()`. This will result in a line of width `ctx.lineWidth/2`, since half of the line will be covered by the shape itself. However, his won't work for other methods such as `ctx.drawImage()` or `ctx.putImageData()`. Please specify how exactly you're drawing these shapes to the canvas to receive some more detailed help.

Edit: I think you can use the solution you already mentioned, you just need to make the non-black part of your image transparent. You can do this by editing the the imageData of the canvas:

```
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var imageData = ctx.getImageData(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
for (let i=0;i<imageData.data.length;i+=4){
    if (shouldBeTransparent(imageData.data[i],imageData.data[i+1],imageData.data[i+2]){
        imageData.data[i+3] = 0;
    }
}
ctx.putImageData(imageData,0,0);

function shouldBeTransparent(r,g,b){
    return r!=0||g!=0||b!=0;
}
```

This will make all pixels that are not entirely black transparent, so you can continue with the method you already mentioned.

Comment: I am not drawing these shapes. It is a png which gets loaded into a canvas. I need to detect the black shapes, because I want to implement a collision warning.

Comment: So what exactly are you trying to achieve? Collision detection could simply be achieved by testing the color of a specific pixel, without doing any extra drawing at all. Or do you want the lines as a visual indicator?

Comment: Yes I know, but the first step would be to detect the black shapes and draw - like in the example above - a red border around them. The red border should represent the minimum distance to an obstacle.

Comment: I just updated my answer; let me know if that approach works for you.